# Can't fetch information from database with urldecode

Tags: php, mysql, urldecode

I have used `urldecode` to receive a member ID from a previous site. The correct ID is being displayed in the URL but I can't fetch information from the database.

members.php:

```
   <?php


$query = "SELECT name, memberID FROM members";

if(!$result = $db->query($query)){
    die('There was an error running your query[' . $db->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  printf ('<li><a href="profiles.php?memberID=' . urlencode($row['memberID']) . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>');

}
?>
```

profiles.php:

```
  <?php

$id = isset($_GET['memberID']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberID = '".$id."'";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["memberID"], $row['name']);
}
}
 var_dump($query);
?>
```

All I get is a blank screen.

Comment: `var_dump($query)` in `profiles.php` before executing it.

Comment: What is the result of `echo $query` in profiles.php?

Comment: `memberID` != `memberId`

Comment: @OneTrickPony post that as the answer. I was looking for typos by Ctrl-Fing for the variable but it ignores the case!

Comment: @sachleen. You must be using IE. Opera has a `match case` option for that :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony Chrome actually.

Comment: `var_dump($query)` gives me `string(39) "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberID = "`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found couple of problems in the code:

**members.php**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  printf ('<li><a href="profiles.php?memberID=' . urlencode($row['memberID']) . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>');

}
```

Here you are using `printf` function which have 1st argument for **format** of string.
Correct that with `echo` statement as below:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '<li><a href="profiles.php?memberID=' . urlencode($row['memberID']) . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>';

}
```

**profiles.php**

```
$id = isset($_GET['memberID']);
```

Here you are setting the `$id` with isset() function return value.
You should instead set the value from GET parameter as below:

```
if(isset($_GET['memberID']))    $id = $_GET['memberID'];
```

See now if it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use the correct capitalization of `memberId` vs. `memberID`.  This is very important.

Do ***not*** pass values retrieved from GET/POST through `urldecode`.  [They already are](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.get-notes).

Comment: Thank you :). So should it just be `$id = $_GET['memberID'];`?

Comment: @PAHemingstam generally preferred to use `$id = isset($_GET['memberID']) ? trim($_GET['memberID']) : null`.  You don't have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled do you?

Comment: `array(1) { ["memberId"]=> string(1) "2" }`

Comment: Interesting. From what I can see I spell it `memberID` in the code now

Comment: My mistake. It says `array(1) { ["memberID"]=> string(1) "2" }`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following based on your code and let us know the results:

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['memberID']) ? $_GET['memberID'] : 0;
if($id > 0){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberID = '".$id."'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    if($result){
        echo "Rows found: " + $result->num_rows;
    } else {
        echo "No rows found";
    }
} else {
    echo "memberID is 0";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is memberID an int field in the database or a string field? If it is an int field then remove the single quotes in your query on profiles.php.

Comment: MySQL will automatically convert strings to integers when necessary, this answer is wrong.

Comment: Please put this (As seen at php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) at the beginning of the page and let us know if anything new shows up: 

ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Or put an echo statement after each variable and after your while loop, then see how many of the echo statements get displayed.

Comment: It says `1 (Members name)`